# php pcntl_fork(): Use of parent's sqlite3 object in childs?

Tags: php, multithreading, sqlite, fork

I read somewhere here, file descriptors and database connections are shared between parent and child(s) created by fork(), and this could lead to problems.

Which are the problematic conditions?

I want to fork() multiple childs and use the same SQLITE3-database in each of the childs.

Is it save to use the one SQLITE3-object created before the fork()? 
This object is copied to the child, but what does this mean?

Can all childs access the same database (read and write) simultanously using their copy of the parent's object?

```
<?
$db = new SQLite3("file.sqlite");

for( $i=0; $i<10; $i++ ) {

    $p = fork();

    // As a child:
    if( !$p ) {

       // do some reads/writes
       $db->query("SELECT a,b, FROM T..");

       $db->query("INSERT INTO T SELECT ...");
       $db->query("UPDATE T SET a=5 WHERE ...");

       exit(0);
    }
}
?>
```

Or is it necessary for every child to create its own object (and connect to the database separately)? Can I / Do I have to close parent's connection in every child?

```
<?
$db = new SQLite3("file.sqlite");

for( $i=0; $i<10; $i++ ) {

    $p = fork()

    // As a child:
    if( !$p ) {

       // Is this necessary?
       $db->close();
       $mydb = new SQLite3("file.sqlite");

       // do some reads/writes
       $mydb->query("SELECT a,b, FROM T..");

       $mydb->query("INSERT INTO T SELECT ...");
       $mydb->query("UPDATE T SET a=5 WHERE ...");

       exit(0);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you forking because you expect the database work to take more time than is reasonable in a web process? If so, you could use a job queue for this, such as Gearman. That will allow you to offload the work in a safer way.

Comment: You absolutely should not do this. Sqlite is a file based database so every write operation needs to lock the whole "database" until the operation is finished. All other processes (forks) have to wait. In fact your code nearly ensures that there will run exactly one fork at any time, no mater how many processes you fork. All of them will have to wait at the first INSERT statement.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use SQLite (or any other file based database system) in forking code, when the forks have to access the same SQLite file.

If you write to a SQLite database the SQLite library has to lock the whole file. The lock is released, when the write operation is finished. Other processes have to wait until this lock is released before they may write to this database.

In your example the SQLite serializes all forks. All of them have to wait until the last fork has finished writing to the database.

Instead of SQLite you shoud use some 'real' database systems like MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same question. Since there are no real answers yet, here is what I found.
You should absolutely **open the DB-Connection in each Child and in the Parent after you forked**. Otherwise you risk corrupting your DB file (I've been through that...).

Sources:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-open.php (see 1st Tip)
- http://sqlite.org/c_interface.html (see 5.0 Multi-Threading And SQLite)

p.s.: Too all people advising against using SQlite in Multithreading applications. Yes, you have to be careful. Yes it is possible when you know, what you are doing. No, sometimes there are no better alternative options.

p.p.s: I'm talking about php-cli here. I wouldn't try to use pcntl_fork in a webserver environment.

Answer (score 1):

## It is a mistake to dismiss the most powerful tools in the toolbox

The modern computing world only works because computers are able to multitask, as soon as someone mentions concurrency issues or threading, everyone runs away with their tail between their legs.

***Concurrency works, bitches ...***

If the programmer cannot think of a way to achieve concurrent execution; *that's a failure of the programmer*, not a failure of concurrent execution, not a failure of the database driver you want to use, not a failure of anything but imagination.

### The task at hand ...

It's not clever to try and use SQLite databases from multiple threads, but note:

*That says absolutely nothing about how many threads **you** can use, only that SQLite should probably be restricted to one*

This means that with a few minutes thought; your code can use as many threads as it requires, so long as it has a way to dispatch read and write operations to another thread, and if necessary retrieve their responses.

### How To

This is by no means a final implementation, it is a big push in the right direction, to get you thinking in the right kind of way.

I'm not sure of the nature of the operation, or the data, the following is the simplest version of the idea, enough to get you started, and or tempt you to read about it ;)

```
<?php

class DataReader extends Stackable {
    public function __construct($sql) {
        $this->sql = $sql;
    }

    public function run() {
        $result = $this->worker
            ->getHandle()
            ->query($this->sql);

        /* note, build normal array in method scope */
        $data = [];
        if ($result) {
            while (($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)))
                $data[] = $row;
            /* write the whole array at once to the object */
            $this->result = $data;
        }

        var_dump($this);
    }

    public function getResult() {
        return $this->result;
    }

    protected $sql;
    protected $result;
}

class DataWriter extends Stackable {

    public function __construct($sql) {
        $this->sql = $sql;
    }

    public function run() {
        $result = $this->worker
            ->getHandle()
            ->query($this->sql);
        if ($result) {
            $this->result = true;
        } else $this->result = false;
        var_dump($this);
    }

    public function getResult() {
        return $this->result;
    }

    protected $sql;
    protected $result;
}

class DataWorker extends Worker {

    public function __construct($db, $flags = SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE, $key = null) {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->flags = $flags;
        $this->key = $key;
    }

    public function run() {
        self::$handle = new SQLite3(
            $this->db, $this->flags, $this->key);

        if (!self::$handle) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "The SQLite3 database \"{$this->db}\" could not be opened");
        }
    }

    public function getHandle() {
        return self::$handle;
    }

    protected $db;
    protected $flags;
    protected $key;

    protected static $handle;
}

/* extending from Pool makes all things simple */
class DataManager extends Pool {

    public function __construct($db, $flags = SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE, $key = null) {
        /* creates a pool of 1, which opens the SQLite3 database */
        parent::__construct(1, DataWorker::class, [
            $db, $flags, $key
        ]);
    }

    protected $db;
    protected $flags;
    protected $key;
}

$worker = new DataManager("test.db");

$worker->submit(
    new DataReader("SELECT * FROM `test`"));

$worker->submit(
    new DataWriter("INSERT INTO `test` VALUES('140');"));
?>
```

Fetching data from DataReader isn't at all difficult, the rest of the logic should become apparent to you after you have read both of the gist links in:

https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/blob/master/README.md